# Elasticsearch - scripted sorting by date(s) field ascending with specific input date

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets assume i have this kind of document (events):

```
[
    {
        "title": "Foo",
        "dates": [
            "2019-07-01",
            "2019-07-15",
            "2019-08-01"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Bar",
        "dates": [
            "2019-07-18"
        ]
    }
]
```

And i want to perform a search that finds all events happening in a given datespan, so i search for all events that take place in between the 10th of july (2019-07-10) and the 10th auf august (2019-08-10).

The query wont be the problem but if i want to display the events in an ascending order (so the "Foo" event is ranked before because the 15th of july comes before the 18th) - how do i sort that correctly?

I thought about using a script to sort my documents, maybe by filtering the dates so only valid dates remain and then use the timestamp from the first date value to do a simple numeric ordering. But how would i filter the dates by the script?

Could i use a "script field" and pass my fromDate and toDate to copy the filtered dates onto a new field (lets say validDates) and use THAT field for sorting?

BTW: the index will only contain a few thousand events.

**UPDATE:**

After some research it looks like this can not be done without using nested objects instead of arrays. Please correct me if i am wrong, i would have preferred to use a simple array of dates over the nested type...

Comment: You need nested objects for filtering the values on which you want to sort. I think you have already read this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting

Comment: Yes, thank you @PierreMallet i came across this information via this site: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sort-by-next-date-in-range-from-array-of-dates/48188